# To 'overlay' 2 dataframes with noted differences

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

2 simple dataframes that I want to 'overlay' them, i.e., if the value of the cell in df_history but not in df_now, it will be added into the new df_now with a prefix, like:

[image]

What I tried is:

1. Convert the 2 dataframes into separate dictionaries
2. Find out the difference, from df_history to df_now
3. Update the dict_now according to dict_history
4. Write the dict_now to a new dataframe

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import os, math

csvfile_now = StringIO(
"""Name Project_A   Project_B   Project_C   Project_D
Mike    2           8
Jane        7       
Kate    17          
""")

csvfile_history = StringIO(
"""Name Project_A   Project_B   Project_C   Project_D
Mike        7       
Jane        8   2   6
Kate    11      12  1
""")

df_now = pd.read_csv(csvfile_now, sep = '\t', engine='python')
df_history = pd.read_csv(csvfile_history, sep = '\t', engine='python')

df_now = df_now.set_index('Name')
df_history = df_history.set_index('Name')

dict_now = df_now.to_dict('index')
dict_history = df_history.to_dict('index')

new_value_list = []
# as ['Mike|Project_B|7.0', 'Jane|Project_C|2.0', 'Jane|Project_D|6.0', 'Kate|Project_C|12.0', 'Kate|Project_D|1.0']

for k, v in dict_now.items():
    for son_key, son_value in v.items():
        if math.isnan(son_value) and not math.isnan(dict_history[k][son_key]):
            new_value_list.append(k + '|' + son_key + '|' + str(dict_history[k][son_key]))

for each in new_value_list:
    mother_key, son_key, value = each.split('|')
    dict_now.update({dict_now[mother_key][son_key]: '(history) ' + value})
```

But the dictionary is not updated but extended:

```
{'Mike': {'Project_A': 2.0, 'Project_B': nan, 'Project_C': nan, 'Project_D': 8.0}, 'Jane':     {'Project_A': nan, 'Project_B': 7.0, 'Project_C': nan, 'Project_D': nan}, 'Kate': {'Project_A': 17.0, 'Project_B': nan, 'Project_C': nan, 'Project_D': nan}, nan: '(history) 7.0', nan: '(history) 2.0', nan: '(history) 6.0', nan: '(history) 12.0', nan: '(history) 1.0'}
```

What's the right way to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `(history)` to the not null value in `df_history` then update the not null value in `df_now` with `df_history`

```py
df_now = df_now.set_index('Name')
df_history = (df_history.set_index('Name')
              .astype('Int64')
              .astype(str).radd('(history) ')
              .mask(lambda d: d.eq('(history) <NA>')))

df_now.update(df_history, overwrite=False)
```

```
print(df_now)

     Project_A    Project_B     Project_C    Project_D
Name
Mike       2.0  (history) 7           NaN          8.0
Jane       NaN          7.0   (history) 2  (history) 6
Kate      17.0          NaN  (history) 12  (history) 1
```